# How to calculate image gradient with respect to homogeneous coordinate vector?

Tags: optimization, computer-vision, derivation

I want to use the direct method of computing the homography between two images to estimate the plane parameters (normal and depth [= distance from camera]) of a 3D plane.

If we have two images of the same 3D plane, then we know that the same point in the images is related by a homography. If one camera is placed at the origin, the homography is given by

$$^{2}H_1=\,^2R_1-\frac{tn^T}{d}$$

where R is the rotation between cameras (3x3 matrix), t is the translation (3 vec), n is the plane normal and d is the distance to the camera. ([see here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html))

Since the homography tells us for an image point in one image where the corresponding image point in the other image is (as long as we stay on the 3D plane), we can write

$$I_1((\,^2R_1-\frac{tn^T}{d})x)=I_2(x)$$

where x is a homogeneous coordinate vector, e.g. (a,b,1). This equation should hold if the baseline between the images is not too big and lighting conditions are similar between images.

If we have a fixed stereo camera, we know R and t and can minimize the following function to get the plane orientation n and distance from the camera d:

$$F = I_1((\,^2R_1-\frac{tn^T}{d})x)-I_2(x)$$

Now if I take the partial derivative of F squared according to d and n, it results in

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial d} = 2F\;\nabla I_1\;\frac{tn^T}{d^2}x$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial n_i} = -2F\;\nabla I_1\;tx_i$$

The problem is the occurence of gradient of I_1. Simply from a number-of-dimensions-analysis, it must be a 3-vector, i.e. the image gradient with respect to homogeneous coordinates. How do I calculate it?

I thought about simply truncating the image gradient to the "true" gradient, i.e. 2-vector and considering the following vector given by the term $$\frac{tn^T}{d^2}x$$ to be a homogeneous vector, which can also be converted to a 2-vector. The problem here is that this term sometimes evaluates to values where the "z-component" of x is 0 and cannot be converted to a 2 vector, so I guess I must stick with the homogeneous representation.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com